# Why can you redefine globalThis and global but not window?

Tags: javascript, node.js

`let globalThis = undefined` gives me no error in browsers
`let [global, globalThis] = [undefined, undefined]` gives me no error in node
However `let window = undefined` throws SyntaxError

Comment: From the spec, section [16.1.7](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-globaldeclarationinstantiation) at point 4c + 4d shows that if [HasRestrictedGlobalProperty](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-hasrestrictedglobalproperty) returns `true`, then you'll get a syntax error. In your case, since `globalThis` is [configurable](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-globalthis), you get `false` (so no error), but as `window` isn't configurable, `HasRestrictedGlobalProperty` returns `true` and so you get a syntax error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`window` **must** be present for the page(frame) to work. Since `window` is declared in [a global execution context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#global_context), you can't redeclare it with `let` or `const`.

Although, it's possible to call the following code: `var window = undefined;` or `window = undefined;`, but it won't do anything to the `window` object. That's because the setter on the `window` object is `undefined` and `configurable` descriptor is set to `false`, disallowing changes and deletion of the `window` property. You can see that with the following code:

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this, 'window'))
```

You are still able to declare your own `window` variable inside any other lexical context, other than the global one:

```js
const test = () => {
  const window = 123;
  console.log('in test fn:', window);
}
test()
console.log('in global:', window)
```

But why can I change the `globalThis` then? You can change it because `globalThis` is the property of `window`. And doesn't seem to have an empty setter and `configurable` descriptor is set to `true`, allowing changes to this property. All that means, you can do anything you want with `globalThis` property :)

```js
console.log(window.hasOwnProperty('globalThis'));
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'globalThis'));
```